# Is there a 64 bit version of CharLowerBuff?

Tags: c++, winapi

I am currently transitioning some C++ code to be compiled for 64 bit instead of 32 bit. The code calls the function `CharLowerBuff(lpsz, strlen(lpsz))` which raises a warning since `strlen` returns the type `size_t` (aka `long long unsigned int`) but `CharLowerBuff` expects `DWORD` (aka `long unsigned int`).

Is there a 64 bit version of `CharLowerBuff` that takes `DWORDLONG` (or something equivalent) instead?

Comment: Just cast it, unless you really plan on having a 4GB string.

Comment: Are you really going to call strlen on a 4GB string? And then walk over it a second time. Perhaps you'd be better using C++ libraries for your text process rather than winapi. Surely you aren't using C strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see one, however `CharLowerBuff(x, strlen(x))` is just the same as `CharLower(x)`, but the latter does not have this `DWORD` problem.

Another approach would be to write your own function to do this operation and take a `size_t` length, which shouldn't be difficult.